# How to set full screen image inside modal without starching image in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

How to set full screen image inside `Modal` that supports all device screen sizes without starching image in react-native ?

```js
<Modal
animationType="fade"
visible={props.isOpen}
onRequestClose={props.onCloseModal}>
   <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}>
         <Image source={"path/to/local/image"} resizeMode='stretch' style={imageStyle}/>
       </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cover` for resizeMode in Image.

```
<Modal
...
  >
  <Image
    resizeMode="cover"
    style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
    }}
  />
</Modal>
```

Comment: I tried with all resizeMode but not worked.